# python os.utime has fails for nfs?

Tags: nfs

I am trying to update modification time of a file on a nfs remote server in python, but got the following error:

```
os.utime(binary_path, (now_ts, now_ts))
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Is this currently not supported in python3?

Comment: *Python* doesn't need to do anything special to provide that support. *Your NFS server* (and your operating system's NFS client library) needs to support it. (That assumes, of course, that there isn't a different issue, like lack of access to the containing directory; still, nothing Python-specific at all).

Comment: ...if you use `strace` to track the syscalls made by the Python interpreter, you can see exactly which one fails. That syscall would fail just as much if you made it from C, or Java, or any other language.

Comment: An easier place to start (assuming GNU utilities) would be trying to run `touch --date='2019-01-01' /mnt/nfs/yourfile` and seeing if that works either.

Comment: ...that said, this could very well be not so much a matter of "support" in the sense of is-the-code-written?, and a matter of deliberate permissions/configuration on the server side. Not every corner of the world considers it good practice for modification times to be arbitrarily mutable -- they lose value as forensic evidence when it's possible to set them to anything other than the current time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure enough, it's not permitted! -rwxrwxrwx 1me me 94K Sep 21 13:38 libdataset_utils.so     touch --date='2019-01-01' libdataset_utils.so
touch: setting times of ‘libdataset_utils.so’: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

You could try (from the command line, but I'm sure there's a syntax in python):

```
sudo chown `your_username:your_groupname filename`
```

Note: The group is usually just your username. 
I think this will fix your issue.

Comment: Apart from the syntactical issue with backticks. this is not correct on multiple levels. While it may correctly suggest that OS errors (such as `EPERM`) are usually "correct" (even though possibly for surprising reasons). This question is about NFS mount and those would very frequently squash root (since local root should wield no special power over server's fs). Of course `sudo` is relatively distro specific matter and the mention about group name even more so, esp. since traditionally default primary group would be `users`.

Comment: To be clear, the backticks make this code try to run a command named `your_username:your_groupname` with the argument `filename`, and pass the output of that command (after string-splitting and globbing) as arguments to `sudo chown`. Obviously, no such command can be expected to exist.